# ApacheBenchmark ab - SSL read failed - closing connection

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, ab

When I am running ab on my website I get a ton of these responses:

```
SSL read failed - closing connection
SSL read failed - closing connection
SSL read failed - closing connection
```

And some times it is successful. I am on a MacBook Pro 10.7.2. What is weird is, someone else does the same test on a very simular machine, not OS Lion, right next to me and has no problems.

Any ideas? I am sure this is something on my machine because I get ab to work all over the place.

The command is simply: `ab -c 100 -n 1000 https://mywebsite.com`

One other thing, when I look in the nginx logs, I do see some requests coming in from the ab so it is working some. And also, the logs do not show the failed ones.

Comment: Your web server logs -- can we see them? At least a relevant chunk from around when you manage to get this error? (is an SSL error being reported by the server or just the client?)

Comment: MYIP - - [05/Jan/2012:16:42:07 -0500] "GET /MYURL HTTP/1.0" 503 512 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3"
MYIP - - [05/Jan/2012:16:42:07 -0500] "GET /MYURL HTTP/1.0" 503 512 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you are encountering a bug in ab [for which there is a patch](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49382).

Comment: I backup that: `brew install ab`

Comment: Still an issue on Mac OS with self-signed certs and `brew install ab`

Answer (score 1):

Question - what happens if you drop the concurrency?  The default ulimit on Lion is quite low  - 256 if memory serves me and you may be running into that here.  If dropping the concurrency sorts it out, just up your ulimit and try again:

ulimit -a (to list); ulimit -n 1024 (or whatever number you wish) to increase it.

Good explanation of it here: https://superuser.com/questions/309106/strange-behaviour-with-ulimit-on-mac-os-x-10-6